# appointments not showing up unless scroll past it

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

This is a strange issue but I hope it sounds familiar to someone and they can help.

I am using Outlook 2010.  When I try to schedule a meeting for April 26th - this seems to be the only day it doesn't work on, the meeting that was scheduled on that day does not appear until you scroll past it a little.  then it shows up.  I have scheduled duplicate meetings because it didn't show up.

Sound familiar to anyone?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted already?  Have you tried a reboot?  Does it do the same thing if you log in as a different user? Have you ensured your graphics drivers are up-to-date?  Have you tried an Office repair via Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: Does the same thing with two different users.  Two different computers.  Office updates are pushed out regularly.  Did not do office repair - reboots every night.